# Flip sorting line order from last to first in php

Tags: php, arrays, file

I want to flip line orders of a text document with 20000+ lines.

Example file:

```
line one
line two
line three
```

I need to flip sorting by line from last line to first line:

Expected output:

```
line three
line two
line one
```

This is my current code, but does not work apparently:

```
$fileLines = file('file.txt');
$reserve = array_reverse($fileLines);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $reserve);
```

Comment: Can you post output of `print_r($fileLines)`?

Comment: line one
line two
line three

Comment: I believe print_r() would output Array ( [0]=>line one [1]=>line two [2]=>line three) if it's indeed an array. Maybe your file.txt does not contain newline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_put_contens()` require a string, not an array:

```
file_put_contents( 'file.txt', implode( $reserve ) );
```

---

- Read more about [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)
- Read more about [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)